# Passing arguments through a file not running with no error messages

Tags: python

Need an extra set of eyes. It's a program running through linux that is supposed to print to different statements depending on the argument you use on the command line after the program is ran. Nothing happens when you run lets say, './donuts.py 15'. Thanks!

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import sys

def main():                                                                               
                                                                                      
    number_of_donuts = int(sys.argv[1])

def donuts():
                                                                                                    
   if (number of donuts) >= 10:
        print("many")
   else:
        print("Number of donuts: " + str(number_of_donuts))

main()
```

Comment: Can you put your full code pls.

Comment: you are not calling `donuts` method anywhere. How in the world these expected lines will be printed?

Comment: This is the full code.
Okay, if I call donuts I get new message that says number_of_donuts is not defined. I thought the sys.argv[1] is defining that variable?

Answer (score 0):

You need to call the `donuts` method inside the `main` method.

And in the if statement you should use a variable name. And the variable name should not have spaces in between. Please follow the below code.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import sys

def main():                                                                               
                                                                                      
    number_of_donuts = int(sys.argv[1])
    donuts(number_of_donuts)

def donuts(number_of_donuts):
                                                                                                    
   if (number_of_donuts) >= 10:
        print("many")
   else:
        print("Number of donuts: " + str(number_of_donuts))

main()
```

Comment: That worked thank you. I guess I don't fully understand the logic so will do more research into this. Thanks!

Comment: No issues. This is a simple flow.

Comment: Also you need to handle the condition where user does not pass argument or a non integer argument in command line.